# android choosing local storage ( files vs database)

Tags: android, file

i would like to know when to use database and when to use file storage for storing list of primitive data types in android for fast access.

for example the data will be a set of strings.

name:xxx , 
emailid:yyy

name:zzz , 
emailid:eee

Comment: What you have tried? Try to google it first.

Comment: If you have a bunch of data which are unable to fetch fast then just store your all data in `database` and access it. If you have little of data two or three variable then you can use `SharedPreference` or use file storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to query your data, to show them in a list or if you have many kvp items, I would suggest to use a database(you can query your data without loading all the items, use them with cursor adapter with list, etc). But if you will have only 2-3 kvp's, you can store them in shared preferences.

Comment: in my app , i have an n numbers of name,email pairs in that case which one will be efficient? n will be like 1000

Comment: in this case I would use a database. It's more efficient loading only some emails, it's easier to maintain your data.

Comment: in my app the requirement  won't query get email for a particular name , instead of that i will access the whole record itself .like get first 100 sets.

Comment: but in my case the data relationship is too small.. i don't need any complex queries.. so flat file structure will be efficient...

Comment: It's ok to use a database even if you have only one table with these values. You don't need to use complex queries to get the data and there are mechanisms that load the data async, but if you  will keep the data in a file, you will have to implement code to  load the data async and it's easy to add the data to the database rather that to open the file and append

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store key-value pairs, there is something even simpler than storing it in a file or database: **SharedPreferences**.

You can look up the usage here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

And a great tutorial you find here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want store key:value info, use sharedpreference.
But if is a long amount of data (just like 1.000.000 key:value data) maybe you need use a database.

I recommend to use a greenDAO database for android proyects.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, if you need to store a lot of similar data (eg : name and email for many contacts), then using a database is the best choice.

SharedPreferences should be used for exactly that : preferences (eg: tuning your application's behavior, appearance, ...)